# React-native run-android Could not determine java version from '11.0.2'

Tags: react-native

I have an existing react-native project which is implemented using mac-os, and I tried to run the project using visual studio code using a windows machine "react-native run-android". but error log says

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine java version from '11.0.2'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get
  full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
  Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
  set up your Android development environment:
  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Solution found! replace Java 11 with Java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downgrading java to 10 or below, i was also getting error with latest version 11.+, switched to 10.0.2, works fine.

Also make sure all environment variables are declared, check [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started#3-configure-the-android_home-environment-variable)

Comment: Thanks, it is working now.  yes with Java 11 it didn't work fine. and I replaced java 11 with Java 8.

Comment: if it is working, can you accept it as correct answer

Comment: oh sorry bro,   did